# Cordova is including a plugin that is not installed, how to remove it?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Edit - This appears to be a problem with the Fovea plugin.  I did not realize that it includes substantial code from the older plugin, which made me think that the older plugin was still being referenced.  I don't know why it's throwing that IllegalArgumentException but it does not appear to be caused by the old plugin being referenced.  So, disregard...

I am working on a Phonegap/Cordova app.  Previously, I started with Phonegap, and used the "SmartMobileSoftware" inapppurchase plugin from https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling.  I installed it per the instructions, by cloning it from git and then using

```
phonegap local plugin add /path/to/src
```

Later, due to various problems, I decided to start over with Cordova instead of Phonegap, and using a different purchase plugin.  I installed the latest cordova with npm, created a new Cordova app in the usual way using a fresh project dir, and installed the Fovea purchase plugin like so:

```
cordova plugin add cc.fovea.cordova.purchase
```

I then copied over my code (html/css/js only, no config files or xml or anything) and everything is ostensibly working, the new purchase plugin loads and initializes.

Here's the mysterious part: the new Cordova apps is somehow including the old billing plugin.  I noticed this because I see this IllegalArgumentException in logcat when my app exits:

```
Service not registered: com.smartmobilesoftware.util....
```

Sure enough, I checked my platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml and it is referencing the old SmartMobileSoftware plugin, and all of the old plugins files are in ant-build/classes.  However, I don't know where Cordova is finding any reference to the old plugin.  There is no reference to it in my new project directory (except for platforms/android), and there is no mention of it in either of

```
cordova plugins ls
phonegap plugins ls
```

Any guesses what's going on here?  It seems like Phonegap put a reference to the old plugin somewhere that Cordova paying attention to, but I don't know where.  How would Cordova include a plugin that isn't listed in "cordova plugins ls"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that both plugins include some of the same libraries, and I was mistaking the new plugin for a remnant of the old one.

Answer (score 0):

to remove use this syntax

```
cordova plugin rm plugin_name_here
```

Comment: That's the plugin I want to have installed.  The problem is that a different plugin called AndroidInAppBilling is being included in the build even though "cordova plugin ls" does not list it.

Comment: strange , you have rebuilt your project?

Comment: As I said, I started over in a fresh project dir when I switched to cordova.  It builds fine (outside of the fact that it's including that plugin).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you have to use the **--save** flag when you run the cordova plugin rm command. cordova plugin remove plugin-name **--save**

This --save flag tells the compiler to also remove it from config.xml , where all the plugins are listed. When you don't pass the **--save** flag, the plugin entry remains in the config.xml and thus when you run: "cordova plugins ls", your plugin is still there..and builds out your old plugin version to the platform level.

This should be highlighted more clearly in the official cordova docs..